# When replacing non-grounding type receptacles is a GFCI receptacle required, or can any GFCI device be used?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci, nec

Under the NEC (it *was* 210(7)(d)(3), but appears to have moved around some), it is permissible to replace an ungrounded receptacle with a GFCI receptacle, then wire further ungrounded or non-grounded (i.e. a NEMA 5 without a ground wire hooked up) receptacles on the circuit to the load side of the GFCI, all in lieu of running a ground wire in order to replace the existing ungrounded receptacles with grounded receptacles.

However: does this permission extend to replacing the branch circuit overcurrent protection device with a GFCI-type circuit breaker (or a CAFCI breaker that provides ground fault protection for personnel)?  Or can only GFCI *receptacles* be used for this retrofit? The NEC's verbiage does not make mention of breaker-type GFCIs...

Comment: The answer aside, I would always recommend rewiring in this situation even if annoying to do so (as long as it is possible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NEC simply states *"where supplied through a ground-fault circuit interrupter"* in this instance, so you can achieve this either by a GFI receptacle, a faceless GFI device, or a GFI breaker.

You cannot however use an AFCI breaker, unless it is one of the new (and rare) AFCI/GFCI breakers. Good luck finding one though. I find one Siemens on Amazon and that's about it.

See "(c)" below.

From the 2011 NEC:

> **406.4 General Installation Requirements**
>
> Receptacle outlets shall be located in branch circuits in accordance
>   with Part III of Article 210. General installation requirements shall
>   be in accordance with 406.4(A) through (F).
>
> **(D) Replacements.**
>
> Replacement of receptacles shall comply with 406.4(D)(1) through
>   (D)(6), as applicable.
>
> **(2) Non–Grounding-Type Receptacles.**
>
> Where attachment to an equipment grounding conductor does not exist in
>   the receptacle enclosure, the installation shall comply with
>   (D)(2)(a), (D)(2)(b), or (D)(2)(c).
>
> **(a)** A non–grounding-type receptacle(s) shall be permitted to be
>   replaced with another non–grounding-type receptacle(s).
>
> **(b)** A non–grounding-type receptacle(s) shall be permitted to be
>   replaced with a ground-fault circuit interrupter-type of
>   receptacle(s). These receptacles shall be marked “No Equipment
>   Ground.” An equipment grounding conductor shall not be connected from
>   the ground-fault circuit-interrupter-type receptacle to any outlet
>   supplied from the ground-fault circuit-interrupter receptacle.
>
> **(c)** A non–grounding-type receptacle(s) shall be permitted to be
>   replaced with a grounding-type receptacle(s) where supplied through a
>   ground-fault circuit interrupter. Grounding-type receptacles supplied
>   through the ground-fault circuit interrupter shall be marked “GFCI
>   Protected” and “No Equipment Ground.” An equipment grounding conductor
>   shall not be connected between the grounding-type receptacles.

Comment: It appears that the situation has changed in a few months' time -- the new requirements in the '14 NEC for AFCI protection of kitchens and laundry areas have motivated both [Square-D](http://www.schneider-electric.com/products/us/en/50300-circuit-breakers/50310-miniature-circuit-breakers/62274-qo-dual-function-circuit-breakers/) and [C-H](http://www.eaton.com/Eaton/ProductsServices/Electrical/ProductsandServices/Residential/LoadcentersandCircuitBreakers/AFGF/index.htm) to come out with GFCI/CAFCI combos.

Comment: As to availability...they seem to be somewhat spotty online (the Siemens units are more common), but they [do turn up](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=27&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CGUQFjAGOBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lowes.com%2Fpd_643661-296-HOM120PDFC_0__%3FproductId%3D50311123&ei=xFu4VIvXLMSpyAS8p4DgDQ&usg=AFQjCNGnRbV6gYlwpv82L-bwMeoxVWT9iQ&sig2=NL8hicVHZTlGUOft0QW3gw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.aWw)